# PCI-Express lanes for integrated and discrete video

Tags: graphics-card, pci-express

This question is a follow-up for my previous question: [Understanding of chipset PCI-Express lanes](https://superuser.com/questions/1157820/understanding-of-chipset-pci-express-lanes)

According to the manual my processor (Intel i7-6700k) has 16 PCI-E lanes.

My motherboard (based on Intel B150 chipset) has 8 lanes, but since it doesn't have any additional PCI slots (except the primary one for the video card), I presume it uses all these 8 lanes up for audio/network/usb/etc.

Now, I want to install discrete video card (GTX 970) and use it in parallel with my integrated card (run Linux as a host with Windows guest).

Will I be able to do it? If integrated video doesn't use processor PCI-E lanes, than it does look probable. But if integrated video uses processor PCI-E lanes, than it can't assing all the 16 lanes to the discrete video. Again, there is an another possibility that processor lanes can be splitted. Processor manual states: "PCI Express Configurations: Up to 1x16, 2x8, 1x8+2x4", which is probably about processor, not chipset PCI-E lanes. So, if a processor can split its lanes and use 8 for the integrated video and 8 for the discrete one - that's also would be acceptable (even if discrete card can utilize all 16 lates, it can still work with 8, and it's better than nothing)

So, the questions are:

Does integrated video uses processor PCI-E lanes?

If yes, than can a processor split its lines between integrated and discrete video as 2x8?

And does it depend on something else (like BIOS, for example)?

I've seen people reported using integrated and discrete video in parrallel with Z170 chipset, but I've never seen anyone used it with B150.